# Resizing text dynamically in LazyColumn depending on scroll - Jetpack Compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I want to make the text to be resizing dynamically when I scroll and them to stay that size when I stop scrolling.

For example here the number `4` to be `20.sp` and the numbers `3` and `5` to be `18.sp` (one index away) and `2` - `6` to be `16.sp` and so on. I think that could be created with
`Modifier.scale()`, but have not found a way for now.

[image]

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalSnapperApi::class)
@Composable
fun Example() {

val listStateHour = rememberLazyListState()
val hourTexts: List<String> = (1..23).map { it.toString().padStart(2, '0') }

Box(
    modifier = Modifier.background(color = Color.LightGray).fillMaxWidth(),
    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
) {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .height(32.dp)
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .background(color = Color.Black.copy(0.2f)),
    ) {}
    LazyColumn(
        modifier = Modifier.height(200.dp),
        state = listStateHour,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.Start,
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(vertical = 116.dp),
        flingBehavior = rememberSnapperFlingBehavior(lazyListState = listStateHour)
    ) {
        itemsIndexed(hourTexts) { index, item ->
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier.height(32.dp),
                contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = item,
                    color = Color.Black,
                    fontSize = 20.sp
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

External dependencies that I am using -> `implementation 'dev.chrisbanes.snapper:snapper:0.3.0'`

Answer (score 0):

You can observe `listStateHour.firstVisibleItemIndex` and calculate a scaling factor depending on the distance an item has to that value.

I didn't test it with the flingBehaviour you're using but this might help you:

```
val listStateHour = rememberLazyListState()
val firstVisibleItemIndex by remember { derivedStateOf { listStateHour.firstVisibleItemIndex } }
val hourTexts: List<String> = (1..23).map { it.toString().padStart(2, '0') 

Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .background(color = Color.LightGray)
        .fillMaxWidth(),
    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
) {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .height(32.dp)
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .background(color = Color.Black.copy(0.2f)),
    ) {}
    LazyColumn(
        modifier = Modifier.height(200.dp),
        state = listStateHour,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.Start,
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(vertical = 116.dp)
    ) {
        itemsIndexed(hourTexts) { index, item ->
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier.height(32.dp),
                contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = item,
                    color = Color.Black,
                    fontSize = 20.sp,
                    modifier = Modifier.scale(
                        scaleText(
                            firstVisibleIndex = firstVisibleItemIndex,
                            itemIndex = index
                        )
                    )
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

fun scaleText(firstVisibleIndex: Int, itemIndex: Int): Float {
    val distance = abs( firstVisibleIndex - itemIndex)
    return 1f - distance * .2f
}
```